# What's the point of using high isolation-level when in autocommit mode?

Tags: sql, database, isolation-level

I don't see a reason why anything higher than READ COMMITTED is useful in autocommit mode.
Autocommit ends the transaction after each query, which in turn releases the aquired locks over the selected data. If the lock doesn't survive multiple queries you can't do consistent reads. So having higher isolation level in autocommit mode only causes locking more data => BAD

Is that correct?

Comment: I guess your query might read the same table twice and get different results.

Comment: @MK you mean multi statement like conn.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE;SELECT * FROM TABLE")?

Comment: @velikolay My guess for MK.'s comment would be that it's about queries with self-joins, such as `select * from employees e join employees m on m.id = e.manager`.

Comment: select statements don't hold any locks or block others (as long as you don't use `for update`). "*If the lock doesn't survive multiple queries you can't do consistent reads*" - not sure what that is supposed to mean. Are you talking about repeatable reads?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it depends on the implementation. Also, SERIALIZABLE for example, should create a read lock.

Comment: Yes, I meant repeatable reads(sorry). It holds lock to prevent dirty reads, non-repeatable reads phenomenon and phantom reads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to assume that a single statement is always safe from concurrency issues just by the fact that it is one statement. This is not true. Let's make an example to intuitively see this. Compare the following two transactions:

```
--A
select * from T where ID = 1
select * from T where ID = 2

--B
select * from T where ID IN (1, 2)
```

Cramming the two reads into a single statement does not avoid *any* concurrency problems (at least not in all RDBMS'es and storage engines). The two transactions have identical locking and consistency properties in SQL Server for example. Some other RDBMS'es use MVCC for each statement. MVCC does not provide serializability. Only under serializability you are always safe of concurrency problems.

Whether you use one or two statements does not make any difference. The same for autocommit or not.

Note, that both versions *not* serializable under `READ COMMITTED`. So you see: There is a reason to not use `READ COMMITTED` and auto-commit at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I still don`t understand. In my opinion with --A you don`t even have concurrency problems as you don`t do repeatable read(you select different data). My assumption is that with READ COMMITED isolation you keep the lock until the end of the query, which can be a very complex one.

Comment: @velikolay hm I thought option A was trivially unsafe. Imagine the following sequence: ID 1 is read as version 1. Both rows are updated to be version 2. ID 2 is read. The reader now has an old version of ID 1 and a new version of ID 2. This state never existed in the database. That's not serializable and maybe a concurrency problem.

Comment: Okay now I understand what you mean. That`s what I was missing in my theory :)

Answer (score 0):

I can answer regarding MySQL implementation, which may have different implementation details compared to other brands like Oracle or PostgreSQL, etc.

You're right, you should just use READ COMMITTED if you can. In MySQL, it creates fewer locks than REPEATABLE READ, and if you use only autocommit, then you don't need the consistent transaction read view of REPEATABLE READ.

In MySQL, REPEATABLE READ is the default transaction isolation level. That's kind of a pity, since it creates a bit more overhead.

You are not at risk for the single statement viewing different results if reading the same row twice, as @MK supposes. Even in READ COMMITTED, each statement is made "atomic" by creating a short-lived transaction read view. Yet it doesn't block concurrent updates. That's the magic of MVCC!

See also http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/

Comment: You make very general recommendations and statements which do not always hold.

Comment: `read committed` ***is*** the default isolation level - at least in Postgres and Oracle

Comment: I have edited the above to clarify I'm talking about MySQL's implementation. I acknowledge the OP did not tag the question [tag:mysql], and other brands may have differences.